# Introduction to electromagnetic waves with easy math

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, resource-recommendations, education

My father would like to understand the physics of light (let's say Maxwell's theory, the wave-particle duality and special relativity) and he's asked me what book he should read. He's a quick learner, but has never done math beyond high school.

I almost told him to read Feynman's Lectures, which is how I first learned about those topics before actually going into physics, but I'm afraid it would be too much work and too much math. Are there any books that cover that material at a slightly easier level but without skipping too many important things?

Comment: Feynman's QED book https://www.amazon.com/QED-Strange-Theory-Light-Matter/dp/0691024170